# Asp.Net Razor Custom style single select list box

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Is there a way to render custom style list box instead of default DropDownList stlye?

scenario is have list of objects in model, let say people = new List. User can select 1 person and submit the form. There are some style for each person list item like

```
  foreach(var p in people) {
    <div class="pblock">
       <lable for="p.Name" >@p.Name</lable>
       <div class="flost-right-top">@p.Age</div>
       <div class="pblock-footer">@p.Address</div> 
    </div>
  }
```

This will display a list of users with some style. I want to be able to select a single item from the list and on submit get selected item in the controller.

The issue with Html.DropDownFor is it only shows a single field. Is there a way to achieve above or just not possible?

Thanks a lot

Comment: your list is loaded properly, you just need selected list id in controller ?

Comment: at the end yes, I thought only way you can do it is with dropdown for selectList ?

Comment: yes you can do this you have to fetch selected id by Request.form["idname"]

Comment: sorry, didn't quite get that. would mind posting some suede code. The thing would be how do you make the item selectable without using dropdown or select?